# Can't apply custom date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, date-format

My cell contains a regex formula to extract a date from a string (result is "mm/yyyy", for example "11/2022").
I define a custom date format (so it looks like "November 2022") but Sheets won't apply it.

What could be the reason and/or what am I doing wrong?

edit: [a sample of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zg5c0JXENvx0rioTefpFzCc7lffjSI026I2UMnWGUIE/edit?usp=sharing). My cell contains the following formula

```
=TO_DATE(REGEXREPLACE(A2, "([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})(.*)", "$2/$1"))
```

note: isdate(mycell) returns TRUE

Comment: Can you share a sample to test?? Depending on what you need with those cell (ie: you don't need sorting or filtering) you could apply =PROPER(TEXT([your regex formula},"MMMM YYYY"))

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I've updated the question with data and link to test spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATEVALUE instead:

```
=DATEVALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A2, "([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})(.*)", "$2/$1")
```

PS: you can also use it in array formula ;)